# Enable Parent Form from Child Form

Tags: c#, winforms

The scenario is this I have a *parent form*, everytime I click the `search button`, a *search form* appears and the *parent form* is just **disabled but can be seen**.

The problem is this everytime I click the `exit button` on the *search form*, the *search form* exits, but the *parent form* or the `MainForm` is **still disabled**.

The code on my `exit button` on the *search form*:

```
MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
mainForm.Enabled = true;
this.Hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates a new instance of the MainForm class. This new instance is not the original one that has launched the search form. Obvioulsy the first instance is still disabled, while the new one is enabled, but you can't see it because is not shown

Usually this problem could be solved in various ways.

- Pass the instance of the form (MainForm) that opens the search form
  to the search form
- Register the main instance to be notified when  the search form closes
- Create and raise you own event that signal to an external form that
  the search ended

**How to register the MainForm to be notified of the close of SearchForm**
The code of the MainForm that launch the Search Form should be changed to something like this
**EDIT** This approach requires that you close effectively the SearchForm. A simple Hide will not close the form and thus no closing event will be raised by the SearchForm

```
SearchForm f = new SearchForm();
// Here the current (this) instance of the MainForm requires 
// to be notified of the closing of the search form
f.Closing += new System.ComponentModel.CancelEventHandler(OnSearchClosing);
this.Enabled = false;
f.Show();
....
```

and add this code to get notified when the search form close

```
// When the search form closes you get this event 
// Here `this` is the correct instance of the MainForm (the one disabled)
private void OnSearchClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```

**How to pass the MainForm instance calling the SearchForm instance**
The second approach is, in my opinion, less preferable because you will force the search form to take a reference to the main form and you will manipulate the MainForm from the SearchForm.
In this way you pass a reference of the MainForm to the SearchForm and use that reference to re-enable the mainForm

```
// In the calling code of the search form pass the reference to the caller
SearchForm f = new SearchForm(this);
f.Show();
```

In the form constructor of SearchForm receive the reference and store in a global class variable

```
public class SearchForm:Form
{
    private MainForm _callerForm;
    public void SearchForm(MainForm callingForm)
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         _callerForm = callingForm;
         _callerForm.Enabled = false;
    }

    // ...  somewhere in this class
    _callerForm.Enabled = true;
    this.Hide();
    // ....
}
```

**How to create and raise a custom event**
There is a third approach that has the benefits of the first one and leave the responsability of the notification in the hand of the developers (meaning that you can raise your own event and, whichever is interested in the event could handle its own business)

Create a custom event in the SearchForm

in SearchForm.cs

```
// Build a delegate that returns nothing and receive nothing
// Define an event based on that delegate
public delegate void OnSearchEnded();
public event OnSearchEnded SearchEnded;

... somewhere in this class
// If some external entity choose to be notified when whe have finished search
// raise the event to which this external entity has subscribed (MainForm)
if(SearchEnded != null)
    SearchEnded();
    ....
```

in MainForm.cs

```
SearchForm f = new SearchForm();
// Here the current (this) instance of the MainForm infom the SearchForm 
// that it wants to be notified when the search end
f.SearchEnded += new SearchForm.OnSearchEnded(EnableThisForm);
this.Enabled = false;
f.Show();
....

// Here the main form receives the notification from the Search Form
public void EnableThisForm()
{
   this.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: So what should I do to call mainForm.Enabled from child form?

Comment: I like the 1st approach.. the second is complicated at my level, I guess I should use the first and find out why its not working. Thanks Steve for helping.

Comment: Well, try to put a breakpoint in the OnSearchClosing and see what happens when you comment out the Hide and close effectively the Search Form

Comment: Last question Steve, what should I put in the Exit(button) in my Search Form if all the work is in mainForm?

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution would be to make the search form a *modal dialog*. Whenever a modal dialog is opened, its parent form is automatically disabled.

You can do this by changing the code on your parent form that creates the search form to:

```
searchform.ShowDialog(this);
```

This will disable the parent form until the search form closes, then the parent form will be automatically re-enabled.

Comment: Haha.. didn't think about it. Great Idea. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass the MainForm to the SearchForm, this way before you close the search form you will be able to hide the original MainForm without creating a new one. See the code bellow :

```
public class MainForm:Form
{
    private SearchForm searchForm;//for keeping the search form
    public MainForm()//your main form constructor
    {

    }
    this.searchBtn.Click+=(s,e)=>
    {
        if(this.searchForm == null)
        {
            this.searchForm = new SearchForm(this);//creating new searchForm if it does no exist
            this.searchForm.Show();
            this.Enabled = false;
        }

    };

}

public class SearchForm:Form
{
    private MainForm mainForm;//this will keep the original mainform
    public SearchForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    this.OnFormClosing+=(s,e)=>
    {
        this.mainForm.Enabled = true;   
    };
}
```

This will close the search form every time and create a new instance of it when you click the search button. If you want to hide it you should use this code :

```
public class MainForm:Form
{
    private SearchForm searchForm;//for keeping the search form
    public MainForm()//your main form constructor
    {

    }
    this.searchBtn.Click+=(s,e)=>
    {
        if(this.searchForm == null)
        {
            this.searchForm = new SearchForm(this);//creating new searchForm if it does no exist
            this.searchForm.Show();
            this.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Enabled = false;
            this.searchForm.Show();
        }

    };

}

public class SearchForm:Form
{
    private MainForm mainForm;//this will keep the original mainform
    public SearchForm(MainForm mainForm)
    {
        this.mainForm = mainForm;
    }

    this.OnFormClosing+=(s,e)=>
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.mainForm.Enabled = true;   
        this.Hide();
    };
}
```

basically this is the easiest way to do this without complicated events and so on. I hope this solves your issue if not i am here to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
UpgradeLicenseDialog dialogBox = new UpgradeLicenseDialog();
dialogBox.FormClosing+=dialogBox_FormClosing;
dialogBox.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
this.Enabled = false;
dialogBox.Show();`
```

use from clossing event to enable parent...

> private void dialogBox_FormClosing(object sender,    System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
>           {
>               this.Enabled = true;
>           }